# Can't access object literal property using getter in ES6 module

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, getter, ecmascript-5

I was looking for a way to self-reference an object to access it's property when I discover the [ES5 `getter` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616262/802365) (see. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)).

I'm working with NPM module and can't access the `canvas` property.

#### *config.js*

```
import path from "path";
import layout from "./layouts";

const config = {
  canvas: { width: 80, height: 80 },
  layout: {
    get base() {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(this.canvas);
      return layout.base.bottom(this.canvas);
    },
    get annotation() {
      return layout.annotation.top(this.canvas);
    }
  }
};
export default config;
```

#### *layouts.js*

```
export default {
  annotation: {
    top: options => ({
      x: options.width / 2,
    })
  },
  base: {
    bottom: options => ({
      x: options.width / 2,
    })
  }
};
```

#### Error

```
{ base: [Getter], annotation: [Getter] }
undefined 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined                                                                                                                                          
    at Object.bottom (/data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/src/layouts.js:13:10)                                                                                                                  
    at Object.get base [as base] (/data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/src/config.js:17:26)                                                                                                       
    at generateSvg (/data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/index.js:15:40)                                                                                                                          
    at /data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/index.js:39:5                                                                                                                                         
    at /data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js:46:5
```

#### Question

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2):

You have nested object literals.  The inner `layout` object literal does not know it has a parent so `this` in your getters for `layout` refers to `config.layout`.

You could use object shorthand syntax to make this better.

```
import path from "path";
import layouts from "./layouts";

const canvas = {
  canvas: { width: 80, height: 80 }
}

const layout = {
  get base() {
    return layouts.base.bottom(canvas);
  },
  get annotation() {
    return layouts.annotation.top(canvas);
  }
}

export default {
  canvas, layout
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`.canvas` is not a property of the `layout` object but of the `config` one, so you cannot access it using `this` (which refers to `layout`, as your log shows). Instead, use

```
import path from "path";
import layout from "./layouts";

export default const config = {
  canvas: { width: 80, height: 80 },
  layout: {
    get base() {
      return layout.base.bottom(config.canvas);
    },
    get annotation() {
      return layout.annotation.top(config.canvas);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Chris, the `this` wasn't referencing my top object `config`, but the parent object `layout`.

Moving up the getter solve this.

```
const config = {
  get layout() {
    return {
      base: layout.base.bottom(this.canvas),
      annotation: layout.annotation.top(this.canvas)
    };
  }
}
```